# How to Store common query statements (Kusto.Explorer, KQL, Kusto, Azure Data Explorer, ADX)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there a way to store common query statements in Kusto.Explorer for future use.  For example:

Most of my queries start with:

```
set notruncation;
set maxmemoryconsumptionperiterator=68719476736;
set servertimeout = timespan(15m);
```

I would like to use a 'variable name' to reference these instead of explicitly calling them out every time.  Something like this:

```
Setlimitations
T
| summarize count() by Key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` statements, when used, must be specified as part of each request.

However, you can define a [request limits policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/request-limits-policy) on the default / a custom [workload group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/workload-groups) with the same settings, and those will apply to all requests classified to that workload group.

also see: https://y0nil.github.io/kusto.blog/blog-posts/workload-groups.html

do note that always running with `notruncation`, a very high `maxmemoryconsumptionperiterator` and an extended `servertimeout` probably indicates some inefficiency in your workload, and you may want to revisit the reason for these being used to begin with

- e.g. if you're frequently [exporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/) large volumes of data, you may prefer exporting them to cloud storage instead of via a query.